# Storybook - how to show full code example on story tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

Im using storybook to write react components. I want to reuse some component props, so that I don't have to duplicate data in every story.

I thought I could do this with the *Storybook* *args*. But it seems that if I use args, then the whole story is not shown in the story tab. This is unfortunate, since the story tab is often the first place users of the components look for the example code, and if they only see ...args, they won't get far:

[image]

Is there a way to show the full source code in the story tab, without duplicating the code in every story?